# Passing a condition as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements, boolean

Is it possible to pass a condition as parameter as you do with actions?

Here's an example.

```
public void Test(Action action, Condition condition);
```

...

```
Test( () => Environment.Exit(0), () => variable == variable2 );
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try passing the second argument as type `Func<Boolean>`.  The code should work as you have it in the second part of your question:

```
public void Text(Action action, Func<Boolean> condition) {
    if (condition()) action();
}
```

EDIT: Note that what you would be doing in your usage example is creating a [Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) containing the captured variables variable and variable2.  You should understand the implications of closures before using them in this way.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot! And thanks even more for the link about Closures :)